# Selenium won't copy text to the clipboard when I send keys

Tags: python, selenium

This was working a few weeks ago and the site i'm testing hasn't changed anything. sometimes it highlights the text I need but it won't copy it to the clipboard , sometimes it works; rarely now but it was working correctly every time when I wrote it and that was without doing time.sleep(). I've started to get an error message back now though.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")

driver.switch_to.frame(0)

upload_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
"#selectfilebox input[type=file]")
upload_input.send_keys("/home/ro/Documents/Aaatrack.pdf")

upload_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Upload")
upload_button.click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "inpfilelink")))

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("inpfilelink")
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")
```

here's the error I sometimes get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "file wrap.py", line 27, in <module>

    elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a")

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 328, in send_keys

    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 454, in _execute

    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute

    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Stacktrace:

    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmp8lWb_m/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9981)

    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmp8lWb_m/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12517)

    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmp8lWb_m/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)

    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp8lWb_m/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)

    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmp8lWb_m/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

I've checked the element with firebug and it's still there with the same name.

Comment: See the changed answer!

Answer (score 0):

`Problems happens because when you hover over the Download link, an alert pops up and shows` **Press CTRL + C to copy to clipboard now**.

To me following code is working fantastic!-

It prints web share link of the uploaded document and pastes copied link into the below text area `//*[@id='linklisttextarea']`. So it becomes four times!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

upload_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
"#selectfilebox input[type=file]")
upload_input.send_keys("C:\abc.pdf")

upload_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Upload")
upload_button.click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='linklisttextarea']")))

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Download Link:')]/following-sibling::td[1]/input")
share_lnk =elem.get_attribute('value')
print share_lnk
lnk = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inpfilelink']")
print "Your web linkk is %s"%(lnk.get_attribute('value'))
txt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='linklisttextarea']")
txt.send_keys(share_lnk)
txt.send_keys(share_lnk)
txt.send_keys(share_lnk)
txt.send_keys(share_lnk)
driver.quit()
```